# How to sort_by date in Ruby (not Rails)?

Tags: ruby

I know that Rails has sorting methods built into ActiveRecord, but I am just writing a plain-old ruby script and would love to sort the records from an array by date.

The date would be stored in one of the cells of the multi-dimensional array.

What's the best way for me to approach this, so I can get to the point where I just do `sort_by_date` and I indicate either `ASC` or `DESC`?

I don't have to use the method `sort_by_date`, but the idea is I would like to be able to easily call a method on the collection and get the results I want.

Thoughts?

Comment: try something and publish what you'v got, preferably some code that can be run independently, in other words, show us the code

Comment: I would assume you want something like: arr.sort_by {|x| x.date}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like this?

```
  class Array
    def sort_by_date(direction="ASC")
      if direction == "ASC"
        self.sort
      elsif direction == "DESC"
        self.sort {|a,b| b <=> a}
      else
        raise "Invalid direction. Specify either ASC or DESC."    
      end
    end
  end
```

A multi-dimensional array is just an array of arrays, so call this method on the 'dimension' you want to sort.

Answer (score 17):

```
def sort_by_date(dates, direction="ASC")
  sorted = dates.sort
  sorted.reverse! if direction == "DESC"
  sorted
end
```

Comment: This is an intriguing solution...Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The way I am doing it right now it is:

```
@collection.sort! { |a,b|  DateTime.parse(a['date']) <=> DateTime.parse(b['date']) }
```

And with the ! operator I am affecting the same variable (otherwise I will need another one to hold the modified variable). So far, it's working as a charm.

Comment: Using `#sort_by` implicitly converts the values based on the block. So it will use more memory, but it's also not going to call parse every comparison.

Answer (score 6):

The following might not work for Date object, but should work for DateTime objects. This is because DateTime objects can be converted into an integer.

I recently had to do a descending sort for DateTime objects and this is what I came up with.

```
def sort_by_datetime(dates, direction="ASC")
  dates.sort_by { |date| direction == "DESC" ? -date.to_i : date }
end
```

Comment: Note that `DateTime#to_i` is an Active Support extension. It's not in Ruby core.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an old version of Rails and `rabl` and it's works for me

```
collection @name_of_your_collection.sort! { |a,b|  DateTime.parse(a['start_at']) <=> DateTime.parse(b['start_at']) }
node do |s|
 # lots of attributes
  s
end
```